# Concatenating Razor variables in ASP.NET MVC4

Tags: razor, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I concatenate my Razor variables?  This is what I have:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Pcs) {
    <li><a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-hdd"></i>
    @item.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName + ' ' + @item.HardwareType.HType </a></li>
}
```

But it's showing the quote marks and the pluses.  How do I put a space between my two Razor variables?

Comment: Just leave a space? or use &nbsp

Comment: Why didn't I think of that.  Razor is smarter than PHP.  Thanks, Forty-Two.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to leave a space between the variables, for example:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Pcs) {
   <li><a href="#" class="btn"><i class="icon-hdd"></i>
  @item.Manufacturer.ManufacturerName @item.HardwareType.HType </a></li>
}
```